# Gradually change TableViewCell layer background color depending on scroll percentage

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I need some help gradually changing the layer background color of a TableViewCell depending on an array of gradient colors when scrolling

```
let gradientColors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.cyan]
```

So the visible cells from top to middle of the screen will have a background color between `UIColor.red -> UIColor.blue` and from middle to bottom of the screen will have a background color between `UIColor.green -> UIColor.cyan`. **Note** they should gradually change background color on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you add tableView on top of the view of UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tblView.delegate = self
    tblView.dataSource = self

    //Make background of tableView transparent
    tblView.backgroundColor = .clear

    // Create gradient background
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.cyan.cgColor]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10 //as an example
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear // make cell to have Clear colour
    return cell
}
}
```

If you want some opacity to make cells more visible you can change ".clear" to "UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)" so the text on top will be a bit more readable

Comment: Thank you, but I want to gradually change the background of the cell not the table view

Comment: Because the view is behind the tableView (make sure your controller is UIViewController and not UITableViewController) and cells are transparent, as you will scroll, the cells gradient changes according to what is behind and therefore it looks like cells are changing the gradient colours. If I understood it wrong, could you send a picture of how it should look like? Do you mean one cell should be one solid colour (no gradient)?